# Asterisk Compilation

Tags: asterisk

I've downloaded the source code of Asterisk from http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/.

I'm getting an erro compiling this from source code in Ubuntu 16.04.1, while trying to invoke `make` :

```
./libasteriskssl.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:321: recipe for target 'asterisk' failed make[1]: * [asterisk] Error 1 Makefile:368: recipe for target 'main' failed make: * [main] Error 2
```

Thanks

Comment: Corrected typos and error highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @arheops pointed, the compilation depends on the version of OS and on the version of asterisk itself. The following works in a Debian 9 with an asterisk v14

Let's suppose you have the source code in /usr/src/asterisk. So, first things first. You have to download the dependencies:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install autoconf
# cd /usr/src/asterisk/contrib/scripts
# ./install_prereq install
```

Then, the configure step:

```
# cd /usr/asterisk
# ./bootstrap.sh
# ./configure <your fancy options>
# make menuconfig
```

Now, the compile phase:

```
# make
```

Installation of executables and libraries

```
# make install
```

Installation of config templates

```
# make samples
```

Installation of service

```
# make config
```

Comment: common. How debian 9 related to ubuntu?.

Comment: Ubuntu and Debianshare the same base and,regarding dependencies, the same system to get the packages (apt-get and aptitude it top of it). The script to get dependencies (install_prereq) is configured for Debian, Red Hat, Open BSD and Free BSD. However, you can see (http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/software-dependencies.html) that it shoud work in Ubuntu, Anyway, I'm going to test the script this evening (Spain, UTC+1) on Debian 16 and I can then document the process

Comment: Ok. Verified. Not so surprisingly, the same Chef recipe works with a kitchen / vagrant machine ubuntu-16.04

Answer (score 0):

Your asterisk version not support that libcrypto/openssl version or you have broken openssl install.

Try different versions, as reference get versions from RHEL/Centos of same year as source code you use.